# Sync service for local SQL Server CE and Oracle DB

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a project at hand and it requires to sync local SQL Server CE `.sdf` database file to an Oracle database on the server. We want to change the existing MS Synchronization framework to something else. Underlying project is an old C# mobile app that needs to work offline as well and when it comes back online, should sync the offline data.

Would I need to create some WebService as well? Would REST Api do the work?

Need some Oracle sync service to do this. Some examples would be helpful.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: I have been searching and all I am finding is Microsoft Sync.

Comment: "...analyze them, determine if they work for you or not, and try them out..."

Comment: Microsoft Sunc doesn't work for us. I am looking for something other than that but not able to find any other service/framework.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do software recommendations here. Read up on what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).